# Reshaping list of 2D points by first coordinate

Tags: list-manipulation

I have a list of (integer) 2d points, and I want to calculate the mean at each point in the first coordinate. So if my data is:

```
data = {{8,0},{7,0},{7,0},{6,0},{6,0},{6,0},{5,0},{5,0},{5,0},{5,0},{4,1},{4,0},{4,0},{4,0},{4,0},{3,1},{3,1},{3,0},{3,0},{3,0},{3,1},{2,1},{2,1},{2,1},{2,0},{2,0},{2,1},{2,1},{1,1},{1,1},{1,1},{1,1},{1,0},{1,1},{1,1},{1,1}};
```

then I want my output to be:

```
{{1, 7/8}, {2, 5/7}, {3, 1/2}, {4, 1/5}, {5, 0}, {6, 0}, {7, 0}, {8,0}}
```

My initial data will be unsorted, but that is quick to fix.
I can do this with the following awkward looking construction:

```
meanByFirstComponent[data_] := Module[{dataUnion, reorderedData},
dataUnion = (Union@data[[All, 1]]);
reorderedData = Table[Select[data, #[[1]] == ii &], {ii, dataUnion}];
Mean /@ reorderedData]
```

but this is very slow for a large list:

```
data = With[{n = 400}, 
Transpose[{RandomInteger[n, n^2], RandomReal[{0, 1}, n^2]}]];
AbsoluteTiming[meanByFirstComponent[data];]

{53.963087, Null}
```

Essentially I want to partition a sorted list that looks like:

```
{{1,1},{1,2},{2,1},{2,2},{3,1}}
```

into

```
{{{1,1},{1,2}},{{2,1},{2,2}},{{3,1}}}
```

and I can't work out how to do this efficiently.

Comment: Also I wasn't sure how to title this question, if anyone has a better idea then feel free to suggest/change it.

Comment: Can we assume that your input data will always be sorted by its first element as you show in your example? If that is in fact the case, will the ordering always be descending by the value of the first element in each pair?

Comment: @MarcoB My data is unsorted, have added that into the question, but sorting is quick.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think the function you want is `GatherBy`:

```
GatherBy[data, First]

(* {{{8, 0}}, {{7, 0}, {7, 0}}, {{6, 0}, {6, 0}, {6, 0}}, {{5, 0}, {5, 0}, {5, 0}, {5, 0}}, ... *)
```

You can then apply `Mean` to each element in the list:

```
Mean /@ %
(* {{8, 0}, {7, 0}, {6, 0}, {5, 0}, {4, 1/5}, {3, 1/2}, {2, 5/7}, {1, 7/8}} *)
```

**EDIT:**  Note that the use of `GatherBy` does not require a `Sort`;  `SplitBy` only compares adjacent elements, so you'd need to sort the list by the first element before applying `SplitBy`.  However, if the data is already sorted, then `SplitBy` might be a bit faster.  If we apply the two procedures to an unsorted random data set of 400 points, as proposed in the OP, we get:

```
AbsoluteTiming[Mean /@ GatherBy[data, First];]
AbsoluteTiming[Mean /@ SplitBy[Sort[data], First];]

(* {0.108721, Null} *)
(* {0.620833, Null} *)
```

(For comparison, the OP's original code takes about 65 seconds on my machine.)

Comment: Apparently the OP wants a sorted list as output. `Gather[ ]` doesn't sort

Comment: I wasn't clear from the OP whether the order of the output was important;  but if it is, one could apply `Sort` to the final list.

Comment: Given I don't have a sorted list, GatherBy followed by sorting works faster for me than sorting then SplitBy (0.05 seconds vs 0.13 seconds on my list of 79800 elements).

Answer (score 4):

```
Mean /@ SplitBy[Sort[data], First]
```

If speed is paramount:

```
Sort[Mean /@ SplitBy[data, First]]
```

which is faster because one sorts a smaller number of elements.

Comment: One has to be careful though: `SplitBy` only compares adjacent pairs of elements, so if the data is not pre-sorted your second method won't work as intended. Conversely, if we can assume that the data is pre-sorted, then there is no need to sort it again: we can use the sorting information to return the list or its `Reverse`, which I'd expect to be faster than re-sorting.

Comment: I knew there would be a function to do this and I just couldn't figure out its name, then it turns out there are two.

Answer (score 1):

Also (> v.10 only) :

```
GroupBy[data, First -> Last, Mean]
```

> <|8 -> 0, 7 -> 0, 6 -> 0, 5 -> 0, 4 -> 1/5, 3 -> 1/2, 2 -> 5/7,   1 ->
>   7/8|>

It seems a little bit faster than with the `SplitBy` approach (when testing the random 400 points data set)

Comment: GroupBy was introduced in version 10 and I'm still running v9 (as v10 refuses to install on my system for some reason), so I can't test this.

Comment: @KraZug v10 introduces also `Association` and `Dataset` which should be efficient to handle large data sets (see doc [here](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/guide/Associations.html) and [here](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Dataset.html)) and which  "work" with GroupBy (as you can see the output here). It is worth to upgrade if you can. You should contact Wolfram support or maybe post your install problem here on MSE ;)

Answer (score 0):

Not nearly as good as David G. Storks's (it'll be hard to beat), but here another way:

```
Mean /@ (Pick[data, data[[All, 1]], #] & /@ Union[data[[All, 1]]])
```

Comment: Actually, if speed is the goal, one can get a speedup by sorting *after* the mean computation:  `Sort[Mean /@ SplitBy[data, First]]`, which is an order of magnitude faster for one large data set I tried.